# How to plot non-linear state space models in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to plot a non-linear model in order to compare it with it's linearized counterpart.

I am following this paper [Nonlinear Model & Controller Design for Magnetic Levitation System](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d25a/42958aa11bbd30171a8e496f412a45d22b1f.pdf) and trying to reproduce the results the authors obtained. In particular I am trying to plot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above equations can be represented in vector format as follows:

[image]

I found no references on how to plot non linear state space model representations on MathWorks.

The Simulink [state-space block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html) is used to implement linear state-space systems and not non linear ones.

So, **how can I plot the response of a non-linear state space model in Simulink ?** Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to construct your non-linear system with the basic Simulink building blocks (add, multiply, integrate, etc...). See https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/build-a-simple-model.html for a simple example of how to build a model, use the same approach whether the model is linear or non-linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Matlab Function Block`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html) to implement the nonlinear equations. You can define the inputs and outputs yourself in this block.

The body of the function block will look something like this:

```
function [xdot, y] = nonlinearss(x,u)

    % define your constants
    g = 9.81
    % etc...

    % your nonlinear set of equations
    xdot = [x(2); g-C/m*(x(3)/x(1))^2; etc...] + [0;0;1/L]*u;

    y = x.';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Using function blocks seems like the way to go. So there is no block implementation dealing directly with non-linear systems that I have missed?

Comment: Well, you can build all kinds of nonlinear systems in Simulink, by applying the separate nonlinear functions to the right states. This would mean that you have to use a lot of blocks and connect them correctly, while this way you can just code the operations.

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting an error when compiling that code. Did you ever come across a similar error? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/430614-simulink-cannot-determine-sizes-and-or-types-of-the-outputs-for-block-matlab-function