# Nonlinear state space models in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to make a nonlinear state space model in simulink. What I have done so far is this, 
[image: figure]

Inside my matlab function i wrote my equations:

```
function [xdot, y] = nonlinearss(x,u)
%define constants
a1=...;
b1=...; 
xdot=[x(2);x(3);x(4);x(5);a1*x(1)*x(1)+...]+[0;0;0;0;(b1*x(1)*x(1)+...]*u;
y = x(1);
end
```

When i run the model it gives me this error:

> Simulink cannot propagate the variable-size mode from the output port 1 of 'untitled/MATLAB Function' to the input port 1 of
>   'untitled/Integrator'. This input port expects a fixed-size mode. The
>   variable-size mode originates from 'untitled/MATLAB Function'. Examine
>   the configurations of 'untitled/Integrator' for one of the following
>   scenarios: 1) the block does not support variable-size signals; 2) the
>   block supports variable-size signals but needs to be configured for
>   them.

my `x` matrix is a fixed size (5x1) vector and also `xdot`. Why it gives me this error and how I can fix this?(Also i have to mention that in the editor for my MATLAB Function Block code i clicked "Edit Data" and i check the variable-size box for xdot and x and i gave [5 1] as the size.)

Comment: Have you changed any of the settings for the block to indicate that`xdot` is a variable sized signal.  If not I wouldn't expect to see that error.  The easy fix should be to put `xdot = zeros(5,1);` as the first line of the code.

Comment: @Phil Goddard as i said in the parenthesis i checked ,for xdot and x ,the variable size and i gave [5 1]  as the size in both of them....also i put zeros(5,1) and still gives me error...i think that there is somthing with integrator....because i pass a 5x1 vector in the integrator and i think the output of the integrator(also input to matlab function) doesnt give me a 5x1 vector

Comment: What im really trying to do is something similar with this answer in stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338098/how-to-plot-non-linear-state-space-models-in-simulink

Comment: You do not have variable sized data, and you should put that setting back to its default value.

Comment: @Phil Gobbard i uncheck the variable size and i set the default value (-1) in size but now it gives me 8 errors....Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not without seeing the errors.  My crystal ball isn't working today.

Comment: @Phil Goddard The error im taking is (x4 times) :Simulink cannot determine sizes and/or types of the outputs for block MATLAB Function' due to errors in the block body, or limitations of the underlying analysis. The errors might be inaccurate. Fix the indicated errors, or explicitly specify sizes and/or types for all block outputs.
Component:MATLAB Function | Category:Coder error
Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1.     
The error says that it is here ...xdot=[(the error is here)->x(2)<-;x(3);x(4);x(5);a1*x(1)*x(1)+...]

Comment: And the last error is this :An error occurred while propagating data type 'double' through /MATLAB Function'

Comment: You need to tell MATLAB that the dimension of either `x` or `xdot` (or both if you want) is 5-by-1.  You can either do this (or do both) by specifying a 5 element vector as the initial condition of the `Integrator` block, or by putting `xdot = zeros(5,1);` as the first line of the code.

Comment: @Phil I tried what you said and still gives me the same errors....also when i put xdot=zeros(5,1) in the first line, it gives me an additional warning in my code: the preallocated value assigned to variable xdot might me unused

Comment: You've done something to your model that you haven't told us.  If I start with a new model, define the initial conditions of the integrator to be a 5 by 1 vector, and drop in your code to a new MATLAB Fcn block (with constants for a1 and b1), then it works as expected.

Comment: @Phil could you tell me how you initialize the integrator conditions? Maybe i did something different from you. Also i didnt touch the model configuration parameters of my model....

Comment: Basically thanks,i think i find it, the code compiled ...anayways thanks